# spring - how to pass a value from an app to a filter

Tags: java, spring, servlet-filters

So I need to add a filter to a spring app, such that after the response has been flushed back to the client, I write to a log file. The values I want to write to the log file are determined within the app. In other words, I would like to pass values, ideally a hashmap of values, to the filter that sits after the main processing has completed.

Is there a best practice way of doing this? I could imagine that I could instantiate the hashMap in the filter when the request first comes in, stash that hashmap somewhere (where?), retrieve it in the app and write to it, and then retrieve it again in the exit filter and write the value out. Is that the best practice way to do it, and if so:

1) Do I have just one filter that fires on entry and exit or do I need to set up two, one for before the app and one for after?

2) Where is the best practice place to stash my data store?

Comment: Hmm.. reading the docs I'm getting the nasty feeling that filters only fire BEFORE processing reaches the servlet. Is that right? How can I get something to happen after the servlet has completed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. One filter is enough. In filter

   //Before calling the servlet. Do something

   ```
   chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);
   ```

   //After servlet completes processing. Retrieve data here.
2. Consider ThreadLocal variables. I am not sure if this is best practice. You will store  data in servlet and retrieve in filter (after 'chain.doFilter()'. But make sure that you clean up the data stored in ThreadLocal before the request is complete because server pool threads so your data in thread locals may not be cleaned.

Comment: Great - thank you - that really helps. I didn't realize that the doFilter method chained like this. That's perfect.. As for variables, what do you think about doing request.setAttribute("mydatahash",new HashMap()) or something like that - I saw that somewhere - using the request as the data store?

Comment: Yes using request as data store is better way of doing. You do not need to worry about cleaning ThreadLocal variables. Sometimes we need to populate data which is accessed beyond servlet layer(example dao) in this case using ThreadLocal will make sense  .SecurityContextHolder of Spring security is an example of ThreadLocal usage.

Answer (score 3):

@Adi's answer explains how to do the job with a single filter and filter chaining.

But instead of using `ThreadLocal`, I suggest that you use `ServletRequest.getAttribute(...)` and `ServletRequest.setAttribute(...)`; see the [ServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) API docs.